# NaN в Math.pow(-9, 1/3.0)

Tags: c#

Помогите найти болие простой и красивый способ решиние проблемы,
при `Math.pow(-9, 1/3.0)` выдает `NaN`

```
if (meg < 0)
{
    meg = Math.Abs(meg);
    sqrt = Math.Pow(meg, 1.0 / 3.0) * -1;
}
else
{
    sqrt = Math.Pow(meg, 1.0 / 3.0); 
}
```

вот мое решение проблемы meg - число которое может быть любым
В докуметации я нашел почему так происходит но не знаю как исправить
[image]

Помогите с решением

Comment: `Math.Cbrt(meg)`?

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь методом [`Math.Sign`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.sign), он возвращает -1 для положительного и 1 для отрицательного:

```cs
var cbrt = Math.Pow(Math.Abs(x), 1 / 3.0) * Math.Sign(x);
```

Также, начиная с .NET Core 2.1 доступен метод [`Math.Cbrt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.cbrt):

```cs
var cbrt = Math.Cbrt(x);
```